# Hide specific context menu in datagrid upon selected row wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, contextmenu

I got one issue on datagrid using WPF Mvvm. I set context menu on datagrid.
here is my code.

```
 <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableCaseRefNo}" 
                             DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  >                                                       
                    <MenuItem Header=" - View Case" >
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ContextCommand}" CommandParameter="VCD"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header=" - Cheque" Visibility="{Binding SyncColumnVisibility, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ContextCommand}" CommandParameter="BMK"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header=" - Cash" Visibility="{Binding SyncColumnVisibility, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ContextCommand}" CommandParameter="UNBMK"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </MenuItem>
               </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

I can show and hide context menu using visibility property. but now i want to enable/disable "-Cheque" context menu upon user selection. how can I disable 'Cheque' context menu when there are 100 over dollars in donate columns(that already shown in datagrid).

Here is my datagrid :

```
 <DataGrid Name="dgv" Background="WhiteSmoke" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItems,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      CanUserDeleteRows="False" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding LstcaseHearingModel,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                              
                      Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
```

Thanks for any help.
frog

Comment: You can use IsEnabled property to enable/disable it. Can you possibly determine the '100' dollars at the VM level? Maybe some code of your VM is helpful.

Comment: Hi tgpdyk, cannot call dependency property inside of LstcaseHearingModel. no idea what did i miss it. Only can call static resource dependency property like SyncColumnVisibility.

Comment: What do you mean "cannot call dependency property inside of LstcaseHearingMode"? Are you calling a dependency property from your Model?

Comment: ListcaseHearingModel is a list of dependency property. It includes name, address, contacts and so on. in Context menu, i dont know why i cannot call ListcaseHearingModel.name, ListcaseHearingModel.address and so on.

Comment: I get it now. In order for you to access the properties, you need to access the SelectedItem property. But another issue I see is that you are binding SelectedItem but it looks like you are using 'selected items' from your VM. There is a difference between SelectedItem and SelectedItems.

Comment: Actually SelectedItems is just a name. I put 's' wrongly and it is not list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use SelectedCellsChanged event to get desired item.

   ```
       private void Dgrd_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           SomeEntity item = (SomeEntity) Dgrd.CurrentItem; 

           if(item.Donate > 100)
               viewModel.SyncColumnVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
           else
               viewModel.SyncColumnVisibility = Visibility.Visible;    
       }
   ```

As you are binding SelectedItem property to SelectedItems property of your ViewModel. So you can check the condition in its setter.

Comment: Hi AnjumSKhan, I used MVVM model. so i cannot get Dgrd_SelectedCellChanged event.

Comment: @DartfrogImi You are using MVVM doesn't mean that you can't handle DGrid's events. I gave you conceptual advice. And I have tested it too.

Comment: do you get any setter example for this? quite newbie in wpf though. i only know setter can set in style.